# Idiomatic way to add an element into sub-list in full-immutable hierarchy

Tags: kotlin

I have the following data-structure:

```
var foo: Map<String, List<String>> = emptyMap()
foo += mapOf(
        "1" to listOf("a", "b"),
        "2" to listOf("a", "b"),
        "3" to listOf("a", "b")
)
```

Map and sub-list are both immutable. I now want to add the element `c` to the list of the first element in the map.

I came up with this solutions:

```
foo += "1" to (foo["1"] ?: emptyList()) + "c"
```

but is this really the idiomatic way?

---

**Update based on @hotkeys answer**

```
foo += "1" to foo["1"].orEmpty() + "c"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative you could check is the approach that the [incubating library `kotlinx.collections.immutable`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable) uses (or just use that library). It allows you to [`.mutate { ... }`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable/blob/master/kotlinx-collections-immutable/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/collections/immutable/extensions.kt#L27) a map, which creates an immutable copy of that map with the applied mutations:

```
val m = immutableHashMapOf("1" to listOf("a", "b"))

val result = m.mutate { it["1"] = it["1"].orEmpty() + "c" }
```

<sup>See also: [`.orEmpty()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/or-empty.html)</sup>

There's no equivalent to `.mutate { ... }` in the standard library, though, but you can define your own extension for read-only `Map` that would do the same.

Comment: What is the main advantage of your solution over `foo += "1" to foo["1"].orEmpty() + "c"`

Comment: @guenhter The `.mutate { ... }` approach is suitable for all sorts of mutations, including multiple subsequent ones. This may turn out more efficient if you often need to make several mutations at once.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration and assignment can be joined unless there is some problem.
Make map & list mutable, as the need is to mutate

```
var foo: MutableMap<String, MutableList<String>> = mutableMapOf(
        "1" to mutableListOf("a", "b"),
        "2" to mutableListOf("a", "b"),
        "3" to mutableListOf("a", "b")
)
```

we can use *when block* like below,

```
when {
    foo.containsKey("1") -> foo["1"]?.add("c")
    else -> foo["1"] = mutableListOf("c")

}
```

Comment: That's the whole point: I want the data-structure to be immutable. With mutable collections, this is no problem at all.